# 3d unity c# car reverse direction movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need some help in moving my player car in the reverse direction in unity C# scripting. The forward movement is perfect but the reverse movement is totally opposite to my expectation. I want my car to move in the reverse right direction when I press both DownArrow and RightArrow but the output I get is the reverse left direction. Correspondingly the opposite is happening when I press both DownArrow and LeftArrow. This is for my 3d game. If at all this helps, I'm using Unity 5.2.0f3(64-bit) in Windows 7

This coding also includes a few collisions.

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;


public class Playermovement : MonoBehaviour
{


    public float speed=60;
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start ()
    {


    }


    // Update is called once per frame

    void Update () 
    {


    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*speed*Time.deltaTime);
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            transform.Rotate(0,-90*Time.deltaTime,0);
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            transform.Rotate(0,90*Time.deltaTime,0);
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            transform.Translate(Vector3.back*speed*Time.deltaTime);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
            Application.LoadLevel("Menu");
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag=="Finish")
            Application.LoadLevel("Victory");
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Destroy")
            transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: how about adding some Code?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Thought it would be too obvious to post the coding. Will add the coding by editing the question. Please wait.

Comment: i'm not too familiar with unity but it looks like you are moving right with a negative speed, which is left

Comment: Just reverse the rotation if the user is pressing the back arrow.

Comment: @MikeT, I'm just rotating, denoted by Rotate() function, for turning. This is why I don't feel moving in that direction. My meaning, I can't exactly understand your meaning, no offence.

Comment: do it your self turn right, then take a step backwards, which direction did you travel from your original point?

Comment: @Gusman, I can clearly understand if you can send me your meaning in code form, no offence.

Comment: @MikeT, I travelled forward from my original point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rotating the object in a fixed orientation but you want it to be reversed when the direction is backward, then just rotate in the oposite direction if that's the case:

```
void Update () 
{


    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*speed*Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            transform.Rotate(0,-90*Time.deltaTime,0);
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            transform.Rotate(0,90*Time.deltaTime,0);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.back*speed*Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            transform.Rotate(0,90*Time.deltaTime,0);
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            transform.Rotate(0,-90*Time.deltaTime,0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        Application.LoadLevel("Menu");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This one worked perfectly as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward*speed*Time.deltaTime);
```

I dont know why your back translation isnt working, but see if this gives your the result you wanted. If the forward is working then simply reversing it could serve as a quick fix.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but yours gave me my previous result only(refers to my left and right directions getting exchanged).

Answer (score 0):

I like that answer by Gusman because it moved me in the right direction, but it wasn't compatible with the game I was building.

I am building the first app in the Junior Programmer series on Version 2020.3.0f1 LTS, and this is my script file PlayerController which is attached to the vehicle.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float speed = 12.0f;
    private float turnSpeed = 65.0f;
    private float horizontalInput;
    private float forwardInput;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        forwardInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime * forwardInput);

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, turnSpeed * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime);
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, turnSpeed * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime * forwardInput);

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, turnSpeed * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime);
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.down,  turnSpeed * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime);
        }

    //We will move the vehicle forward here.
    //    

    //    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed * forwardInput);
    //    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, turnSpeed * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```